# Given $f(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ , for $y>0$, find $P(Y>s|Y>t)$

Tags: probability-distributions

Random variable y with pdf as follows.

Given $f(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ , for $y>0$, find $P(Y>s|Y>t)$.

I am having difficulty computing this. 
I have used bayes and integrated to get the CDF and then used $1-P(y<t)$ and $1-P(y<s)$ and cannot get the correct answer. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint.

You don't need Bayes' theorem. Assume that $s > t \geq 0$.

Then 
$$P(Y > s \mid Y > t) = \dfrac{P(Y > s \cap Y > t)}{P(Y > t)} = \dfrac{P(Y > s)}{P(Y > t)}$$
Can you find these two quantities?

Here's why $P(Y > s \cap Y > t) = P(Y > s)$:

[image]

The interval in which the green and red lines **both** appear above is wherever $Y > s$.

Comment: Why does P(Y>s $\cap$ Y>t)=P(t<Y<s). Should it not be equal to 1-P(t<y<s)? Thank you for your response!

Comment: @RobbieMeaney I made a typo. See the above.

Answer (score 0):

If $t<s$, then $\Pr(Y>s|Y>t)=0$. Otherwise, with $s\geq t$,
$$
\Pr(Y>s|Y\geq t)=\frac{\Pr(Y>s\text{ and }Y>t)}{\Pr(Y\geq t)}=\frac{\Pr(Y>s)}{\Pr(Y\geq t)}=\frac{\int_s^\infty\lambda\exp(-\lambda y)dy}{\int_t^\infty\lambda\exp(-\lambda y)dy}.
$$
For any $\tau\geq 0$, note that $\int_\tau^\infty\lambda\exp(-\lambda y)dy=\exp(-\lambda\tau)$. Can you complete the solution?